# Implementing Color Hierarchy Logic in Recursive Land Subdivision Algorithm (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, image-processing

I am working on a Python program that simulates the subdivision of land parcels using a recursive algorithm. Each land parcel can be further divided into four sub-patches, with each sub-patch potentially being leased or further subdivided by its respective lessee.

As part of this algorithm, I need to determine the color hierarchy, which represents the order of land subdivision and the colors used to mark boundaries at each subdivision level. The color hierarchy is crucial for accurately representing the boundaries in the output image.

Here's a brief overview of the algorithm:

```
The land subdivision process starts with a single rectangular patch of land.
If a lessee decides to sublease their patch, it is divided into four sub-patches, and boundaries are marked with unique colors.
The subdivision process can continue recursively until lessees decide to keep their patches without further subdivision.
```

My question is regarding how to implement the logic for determining the color hierarchy:

```
How can I accurately determine the order in which sub-patches are divided and assign colors to each subdivision level?
What approach should I take to represent the color hierarchy in the output image in reverse order based on the subdivision process (e.g., top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right)?
Are there any specific considerations or challenges I should be aware of when implementing the color hierarchy logic within the recursive algorithm?
```

The recursive function should be written outside the main function which is:
def function1(input_file):
load the image as list of lists of tuple
call the recursive function

Given an example : https://it.imgbb.com/
"color_order": [[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 255], [255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [0, 255, 0], [0, 0, 255], [0, 0, 255]]}

PS: cant use libraries or using global variables, the recursive function out of the main one and not inside try or except.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

What I'm unsure about is how to deal with the problem properly, in an image of a list of rgb tuple lists "what" is inside another cross? How do I follow a hierarchy of a cross that is the first in the area?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3Qjr.png)

Comment: You'll scan the image, in a straight direction, detecting color changes, then following that line, ...etc. Start by just spotting the border lines, where they start and end.

Comment: How this could define the hierarchy?i  have to take into result  if a cross is inside a sub area of ​​another cross

Comment: That is a next step. But you take this step by step. Once you are able to identify lines, you can focus on dividing the scope of your scans into 4 quadrants. But first things first. Have you working code that identifies lines? BTW, the link to the image does not work. Just paste an image with the image-toolbar button.

Comment: I can identify lines by scan the image and get connected pixel != background_colors, like this i get the positions of each cross. 
Btw i edited the post for the image

Comment: Now select the cross that reaches to the 4 borders of the image, determine the sizes of the 4 quadrants it makes and make 4 recursive calls.

Comment: How could i make it for the sizes of the quadrants?

Comment: You know directly from the coordinates of the crosslines

Comment: Could you explain me how?

Comment: Well if you have an image of 100x100 and find the longest vertical line at x=20, and the longest horizontal line at y=40, then your quadrants are (0,0)-(19,39) and (21,0)-(99,39) and (0,41)-(19,99) and (21,41)-(99,99).

Comment: could you post some code example to let me understand better?

Comment: What is unclear about what I wrote? If you have trouble implementing it, then please edit your question and include the code you have tried with, and indicate where it goes wrong.